# SPFx to add watermark to PDF before downloading it

Tags: development, spfx, spfx-webparts

We need to develop SPFx web part, which show pdfs from our document library inside SharePoint online site collection. and we need the SPFx to add bookmarks to the pdf on runtime before downloading it, the bookmark should show the user email address.. is this possible ?

Comment: You'll need to use a library like [jsPDF](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html) to load your PDF file, manipulate it, and then download it.

Answer (score 0):

If what you meant was a component for SPFx, there are tons of it out there. From [React PDF Viewer](https://react-pdf-viewer.dev/examples/add-a-watermark/), [PS PDF](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2022/how-to-watermark-a-pdf-using-javascript/), or [jsPDF](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF). But you will end up with another issue that people can easily bypass this functionality, like sync to OneDrive and direct download from the document library.

If the need is an entire solution where every PDF downloaded from SharePoint Online is watermarked anywhere it's downloaded from, then I don't seem to see that this is possible. Mainly because doing so, is actually touching the machine-level customizations on the SharePoint Online.

However with SharePoint on-premises is possible, by creating a custom [HTTP modules and handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/development/http-modules-handlers) to deal with incoming requests that has PDF extension to it.

Comment: but seems there are some 3rd party tools which provide this feature to sharepoint online, so i thought it is possible to develop a simple solution using SPFx

Comment: If you're trying to manipulate PDF on-the-go while user downloading it, doesn't matter if the user downloads from document library or on page, or anywhere else, HTTP handler is the absolute answer. But you can't do on SharePoint Online, no machine-level customization is allowed.

Comment: But if your objective is just to present the PDF only on page, then you can use SPFx. Like I said, if the user happen to find out the document library and download it manually, then the PDF won't have your customization.